# When is QT_NO_CONTEXTMENU defined?

Tags: c++, qt

In the [Qt documentation on menus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html), they show how to override the Context Menu for a widget. They use the macro `QT_NO_CONTEXTMENU`, but they don't make any comments in the text about this macro, why it's there, or who uses it:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_CONTEXTMENU
    void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event) override;
#endif // QT_NO_CONTEXTMENU
```

When is QT_NO_CONTEXTMENU defined by Qt?

I could see Qt defining this macro for you on systems that don't support context menus, for example. Since `QAbstractScrollArea`s declaration of `contextMenuEvent` is wrapped in this same way, I know I must use the macro as well to be safe, otherwise I risk using `override` on a non-existent function that would never get called. But I want to know what would cause this macro to be defined in the first place, since it seems very odd to me that this would be a macro in the first place, rather than a member variable of `QAbstractScrollArea` that can be set at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This macro gets defined when the `-no-feature-CONTEXTMENU` option is set when configuring and building Qt from source, i.e. using the `configure` tool. You are correct that it's for systems that don't support context menus. These are usually embedded systems (e.g. touch-screen kiosk) that have limited resources so you don't want to bog them down with any extra modules, especially ones that won't be used anyway.